# NodeJS authentication with Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I would like to authenticate and keep sessions via NodeJS with Firebase. Client can't directly communicate with Firebase.

In short:

> Client (browser) <----> NodeJs(firebase-admin) <----> Firebase

I created Firebase client in NodeJS, then I used login method:

```
var firebaseClient = require('firebase');
firebaseClient.initializeApp(config)
firebaseClient.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
})
```

and then I created route to check authenticated user:

```
app.get('/check',function(req,res){
    var user = firebaseClient.auth().currentUser
    console.log(user)
})
```

This method only allows me keep 1 previously logged user.

I would like to use firebase-admin, but I don't know how to keep session and authenticate users

Comment: Look into `passport` as a way to manage sessions. I'm sure there's a package to manage firebase authentication using firebase already made for you, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-firebase-auth

Comment: I used angular fire. You can directly communicate your client (a browser) with firebase. I didn't find solution for described problem.

Comment: @KarolBilicki Did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 18):

You can authenticate clients on their respective devices/browsers using the client SDK, and them get them to send an ID token to a backend service written using firebase-admin (the admin SDK). The admin SDK provides methods for validating ID tokens sent by clients: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: But this makes the users dependent on client sdk's. I'm trying to make a complete REST API Service and didn't find a way to sign-in and out only through cloud functions :(

Comment: This is to be expected, since Admin SDK is intended to extend and complement the capabilities of the client SDKs. However, there's now an API for [maintaining auth state with cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies), but you still need an ID token obtained from a client login. Your best bet would be to combine that with using the client SDK in the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
It seems like I found an alternative. I'm trying to use REST service of Google Identity Toolkit for getting the IdToken from Cloud Functions. Do you see it as a possible solution?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/

Comment: Are you getting it with a custom token or with username and password? If it's the latter, I've noticed the ID token you get is slightly different.

Comment: I'm using Username/Password login. Looks like I'm successful using the Rest Auth. However, i'm stuck with one single point. It doesn't support Signout. Do i need to just ignore it and handle by clearing the accessTokens on client?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka how do you  send the token to the server side from the client?

Comment: You can send it along with the HTTP requests sent by the client to the server. As part of the header is probably the easiest. This use case is demonstrated in this [I/O talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlmizBWJk6A) (jump ahead to the 12:00 minute mark).